# Create Laravel app works even on lock screen

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel app that tracks the life location of users. The problem is that it stops working when the phone is locked. How to send the whole application in the background processes when the phone is locked and then return it when the page opens again.
Or another option so that the application does not stop.
Stop only after logout.
Please help!

Here is the app.
https://followme.folirpolir.com/public/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumption : your app is only web app made with only laravel framework.**

Then the app runs only in browsers and inorder to run the app in background u must give permission to the broswer where u have opened the app.

Comment: I didn't understand if it possible or not. Please gave me more information about giving  permission to the browser and whole process